# How to add Power BI Web part in Web Part page in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerbi

Is there any way we can add Power BI web part in web part page in SharePoint Online?

Answer (score 2):

You can check out [this](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-service-embed-report-spo/) detailed documentation on how to use your Power Bi URL to add it to the Power BI report in SharePoint Online

-Go to Power BI site 
[image]

- Copy the Power BI URL of your published report
  [image]
- Add Power BI Webpart 
  [image]
- Use the report url 
  [image]

Comment: Thanks. I know how to add the Power BI web part in Modern Pages. I was asking how to add it on Web Part or Wiki Page?

Answer (score 0):

In case if you want to add the POwerBI report on a wiki page or a web part page in classic UI, you must use script editor web part. Just click on **Publish to web** option from the file tab in the app service, copy the html/src and paste it inside the script editor web part and you should be able to see the PowerBI report rendering on a wiki or web part page in classic UI.